# Paths are working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, path

[image]

This is structure I have. Page `add-product.php` is in folder `public_html`. Partial page `ConnectQuery.php`  I need to access is in folder `partial`.
My project worked fine on localhost with wamp. Now I uploaded it to server and pathing got screwed.
Error I get:

```
Warning: include(/storage/ssd3/728/17657728/public_html/partial/ConnectQuery.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd3/728/17657728/public_html/add-product.php on line 13
```

Line 13 in `add-product.php` is

```
include __DIR__ . "/partial/ConnectQuery.php";
```

EDIT: There is one more error

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/storage/ssd4/729/17661729/public_html/partial/ConnectQuery.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd4/729/17661729/public_html/add-product.php on line 13
```

Comment: It's very likely just a permission issue, check that the web server's user own/can read those files

Comment: I added every permision to every role and still nothing

Comment: can u do this `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/partial/ConnectQuery.php');`

Comment: I did and still nothing. Same error

Comment: try "./partial/ConnectQuery.php" or ".\partial\ConnectQuery.php"

Comment: Everything looks OK from what you've posted. Can you perhaps share a screenshot of the file names too? Please include _all_ files which are accessed when running your script. I am wondering if there is a case issue happening. Windows is case insensitive, while Unix-based systems are case sensitive. Also, what you do mean by `Partial page`. Which one is a partial page? `add-product.php` or `ConnectQuery.php`

Answer (score 2):

Check the **case** in the spelling of the filename `ConnectQuery.php`.
Is it maybe `connectQuery.php` (like you wrote in another question)? Or `connectquery.php`?

**Windows ignores differences in the case of file names, Linux doesn't**.

Answer (score 2):

usually paths never work the same way unless the development machine and server OS are same and they handle directories and files the same way -

Say if your development machine is Windows your Drive C:// will be there
its not the same in case of Linux and most of the servers are  on linux and hence you're facing paths issue try using a path library in your case

in Node js there is path ;
which will point to current directory from you're running your project and from there on the paths will work with no issues .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP <= 5.2 than you have to try as below

$dir = dirname(**FILE**);
include($dir.'/partial/ConnectQuery.php');

Please try this and if you using some other php version than mention it here

Comment: 5.2 was last supported over 10 years ago, is there any reason why you would think they are using such an old version?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have problems with includes in my PHP projects between localhost and the actual server. I was able to get rid of this by using dirname(__FILE__). In your case you would use the following in your add-product.php

> include dirname(__FILE__)."/partial/ConnectQuery.php";

This bypasses some weird standard include path errors by providing the full path of the current files directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is all caused by directory separator issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the case of the ConnectQuery.php filename.

Windows is case-insensitive which means that WAMP will find a file named connectquery.php even if you requested CONNECTQUERY.php

Linux won't. If you request a file named CONNECTQUERY.php, it will search for this exact filename.

I advise you to adopt a convention : only lower-case letters for filenames. This will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).